# Trouble with FieldItemList::view

Tags: entities, 8

I have a custom content entity that renders fine in its page view and form. I'm now trying to view one of its fields in a table using an EntityListBuilder, but the following code throws an error message:

```
public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {
  $row['id'] = $entity->id();
  $row['email'] = $entity->email->view();

  return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
}
```

Results in:

> **Fatal error:** Call to undefined method
>   Drupal\my_module\Entity\MyEntity::render() in
>   /.../core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/Attribute.php on line 294

Apparently the view builder expects a render() method, which I do not have, and which I do not want to implement, since the entity renders fine otherwise...

Also tried EntityViewBuilder::viewField() with no success.

Even when I'm viewing a node instead of my custom entity, I get the same message.

Comment: As an aside, I don't know why I'm bothering with ListBuilder. I've switched to views now and it's much less of a pain.

Answer (score 1):

The function `buildRow` returns a render array. You can put simple strings directly in the array, because later it will be put in another html structure like a table. An example from core, where it is used both ways (CommentTypeListBuilder.php):

```
public function buildRow(EntityInterface $entity) {
    $row['type'] = $entity->label();
    $row['description']['data'] = ['#markup' => $entity->getDescription()];
    return $row + parent::buildRow($entity);
  }
```

So using the '#markup' element is optional. You can use it to be on the safe side, when you don't know how your render array is processed.

For complex elements you need a render element. The method view() would generates this:

```
$row['email'] = $entity->email->view();
```

But this does not work. The problem seems to be in the custom entity. According to the error message there is a call to an undefined method `render`, which should be defined in `MyEntity`. Your entity does not know how to handle the email field.

If you don't want to theme the field, you can use the value as markup:

```
$row['email']['#markup'] = $entity->email->value;
```

Or you can put the field as an object:

```
$row['email'] = $entity->email;
```

Or you can build your own render array, for example as a link:

```
$row['title'] = array(
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#title' => $entity->label(),
      '#url' => $uri,
    );
```

Comment: The ID line actually works very well. It's the email line that doesn't.

Comment: That makes sense, the error is before the function returns the render array, in your custom entity is no method to render the entity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. In my code, `$entity->email->view()` doesn't generate a render array, but an error message.

Comment: I don't think ListBuilder expects render arrays in buildRow(). For example, if I supply a number of static strings, such as `$row[] = "Hello, World"`, the output is just fine.

Comment: According to documentation the function returns "A render array structure of fields for this entity", but when you check how it is used in core, there are examples, where strings are OK. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The view() method doesn't work either if I apply it to a node's title field: `$row['email'] = $node->title->view();`

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, if you render a field, it will go to the entire render system, you can theme this with your own template and so on. I put two alternatives into my answer.

Comment: Good point, and thanks, your examples are indeed helpful. I guess what I was trying to do is to invoke the default formatter for the field, in the same way that the field is displayed when the entity is rendered for viewing. What I wanted to avoid is to implement the formatter in two places (both Formatter class and ListBuilder). What confused me is that there is a view() method that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've tried the `$row['email']['#markup']` line, but it doesn't work …

Comment: Depending on what you are building you can try to add a 'data'-index: `$row['email']['data']['#markup']`

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. Thanks. I think I'm getting the hang of it now …